# ionic 3 / ionic 4 ItemReorder, reordering is not working on the simulator browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

ionic have nice feature of ItemReorder. Sample code is like following

```
<ion-list reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of listOfItems">
    <ion-label>
      {{item}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
    </ion-list>


reorderItems(event) {
    let element = this.listOfItems[event.from];
    this.listOfItems.splice(event.from, 1);
    this.listOfItems.splice(event.to, 0, element);
}
```

After some time, re-ordering (when you drag & reorder an item) will not work on the browser (http://localhost:4200).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still wondering how to do it:

(IONIC 3)

```
 <ion-list [reorder]="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">

  reorderItems(e: ReorderIndexes) {      
     const draggedItem = this.yourArray.splice(e.from, 1)[0];
     this.yourArray.splice(e.to, 0, draggedItem);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** *Close the browser and reopen again on new browser / Incognito mode, then the reordering function will work.*

I have simulated and figured out that the browsers are not fully supported for this feature. So re-launching on a new window will solve this issue.